Commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$
Let $p : \mathbb{R}^2 \to T$ be a covering space of the torus, with the map $p$ defined by $p(x, y) = (e^{2\pi ix}, e^{2\pi iy})$. Let $G$ be the grid in $\mathbb{R}^2$
consisting of all those points with either $x$-coordinate
or $y$-coordinate an integer. Let $X = p(G) \subset T$. Then $X$ is the figure-eight space and the fundamental group of $X$ is a free group on two generators.

Show that $p|G : G \to X$ is a covering space.
Choose basepoints $(0, 0) \in G$ and $(1, 1) \in X$. What is $\pi_1(G,(0, 0))$?
Show that $(p|G)_*(\pi_1(G,(0, 0)))$ is the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(X,(1, 1))$.

This is an old qualifying exam question
My progress: . I have solve part $(1)$. For part $(2),$ I first consider a maximal spanning tree of the graph $G$ consisting of all unit length paths lying on the $x-$ axis, or any vertical line. Then, by adding one horizontal unit length edge at a time, I get a collection of representative loops in $\pi_1(G)$. This shows that $\pi_1(G)$ is generated by loops that form the boundary of certain unit width rectangles, and connects to the origin by a "straight line." This think this group is isomorphic to the free group on two generator with relators words with sum of exponents in each generator $0$. I am not sure if this is true.
I am completely stuck with part $(3)$. I think I need to find a nicer description of the group $\pi_1(G)$ to solve this part. Any hints/solution would be appreciated.

The commutator subgroup of $F_2$ is the free group on countably many generators.

Do you already know that the inclusion map $X\to T$ induces homomorphism of fundamental groups which is the abelianization of $\pi_1(X)$?

Here's one way to do it. For (2), since $G$ is a graph, its fundamental group is free, generated by all the edges not in a maximal spanning tree. Given the tree you've already found, that means all the horizontal edges not on the $x$-axis. There are countably many of those, so $\pi_1(G,0)$ is a free group on countably many generators.
Let $F:=\pi_1(X,1)$, which is free on $2$ generators, which we can take to be represented by paths in $G$:
\begin{align}
\alpha_k(t) &= (t,k) && \text{horizontal}\\
\beta_k(t) &= (k,t) && \text{vertical}
\end{align}
Then $a:=p_\ast(\alpha_k)$ and $b:=p_\ast(\beta_k)$ generate $F$. Now take the loop of the unit square centered at the origin in $G$, which is equal to $\alpha_0\cdot\beta_1\cdot\alpha_1^{-1}\cdot\beta_0^{-1}$. Then $p_\ast[\alpha_0\cdot\beta_1\cdot\alpha_1^{-1}\cdot\beta_0^{-1}]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in [F,F]$. Also, the covering $p:G\rightarrow X$ is regular: $p^{-1}(1)=\{(m,n)\mid m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, and the deck transformations (integer translations) act on this fiber transitively. This means that $p_\ast\pi_1(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $F$. Since it already contains the commutator $[a,b]$ from above, we see that $[F,F]\le p_\ast\pi_1(G)$. (Another way to see this is from the fact $F/p_\ast\pi_1(G)$ is Abelian.)
Now if $[\gamma]\in\pi_1(G,0)$ is any loop, then the total horizontal distance this loop covers is zero (since it comes back to the origin), and similarly for vertical distance. As an example, consider $[\gamma_{mn}]$, one of the free generators of $\pi_1(G,0)$ from part (2), seen below:

This loop goes $m$ units to the right; $n$ units up; $1$ unit to the right; $n$ units down; then $m+1$ units to the left. So we see then that $p_\ast([\gamma_{mn}])=a^mb^nab^{-n}a^{-m-1}$. Since the horizontal/vertical distance covered is zero, the exponent sums for $a$ and $b$ are zero. In the Abelianization $F/[F,F]$, then, $p_\ast([\gamma_{mn}])=0$. This shows that an arbitrary generator of $\pi_1(G,0)$ (and in fact any loop in $\pi_1(G,0)$ at all) ends up in $[F,F]$, so that $p_\ast\pi_1(G)\le [F,F]$. Combined with the reverse containment above, we have $p_\ast\pi_1(G)=[F,F]$, which is part (3).
